# How do I delete data imports in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have been playing with google analytics and its data import feature. In playing, I have created a couple of data imports that don't do what I really want them to.

Is there a way to delete them once they are no longer required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot delete the "standard" processing time import (see list item 2) in the screenshot):

[image]

In a GA360 account you can delete [query time](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6071511?hl=en&ref_topic=6064627) imports by clicking "manage uploads", tick the checkbox before the data files you want to delete and hit "delete selected":

[image]

As mentioned this is only available in paid-for accounts.

Comment: Would it be fair to paraphrase as: you can delete uploaded files, but cannot delete import schemas?

Comment: Broadly yes. The more important bit is that for processing time uploads you cannot remove the imported data once it has been joined to incoming requests.